# Math puzzle not that hard but i cant find what am i missing

Tags: mathematical-physics

The braking distance for a truck with the speed measured in km/h is $\frac{v^2}
{100}$ meters, the
“reaction distance” (distance driven during the reaction time) is about $\frac v 4$. For save driving,
the distance between one truck driving behind another truck should be at least the sum of the
braking distance and the reaction distance. At which speed will a convoy of trucks have the
highest number of trucks passing a point along the road (within a time unit)?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  And for clarity:  is $v_2=v$?  Or was $v2$ meant to denote $v^2$?

Comment: İt is v^2 sory.

Comment: I don't think you can work this problem without knowing the length of a truck.  Or making some assumptions.

Comment: Actually its basically asking the min of save driving distance. and the lenght of the road is infinite or not mentioned so you dont need the lenght of the truck

Comment: Think that i didnt understand is what is it mean with the "within a time unit"

Comment: İs it askin the max number of trucks who passes in the 1 unit time.so if the number of the trucks is N each speed of the trucks is 1/N am ı correct

Comment: The time unit doesn't matter, nor does the length of a truck, just assign values.

Comment: If one truck is a mile long, I think your answer will be different than if one truck is an inch long.

Comment: @B.Goddard  As I understand the problem, the length of a truck is irrelevant.  The optimal gap should be independent of that.  True, the actual number of trucks that pass in a given time interval will depend on the length, but the gap should not.

Comment: The problem is i it just simply asking the min(v^2/100+v/4)but its can be infinitly small

Comment: Small distance more trucks

Comment: @Creedance  Yes, but if $v=0$ then no trucks at all pass a point in a given interval, so that's not optimal.

Comment: First do it for points (assuming a truck is a point).  At speed $v$, how many points pass in an hour (assuming they all maintain safe distance).  Now optimize that number in terms of $v$.  Then, to check @B.Goddard's issue, assume that the "points" have length $L$ and repeat the calculations.  I think the optimal $v$ should be the same but it is definitely worth checking.

Comment: So what is the min of the V.actually this question is from the CAS intelligent scale test so the answer may can be the "smallest vlaue of the given sum"

Comment: @B.Goddard  Counter to my intuition, the length of the truck definitely does matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the safe driving distance should be $d_s(v)=\frac{v^2}{100}+\frac{v}{4}$.
Then the distance between the front of the trucks should be $d =d_v+l$ with $l$ being the length of one truck.
Then the formula of trucks passing per second (if you convert the velocity to m/s and the distance to m) is $\frac{d}{v}=\frac{\frac{v^2}{100}+\frac{v}{4}+l}{v}$ and then you need to find the minimum of this function.

Comment: Ok thx but can v equal to one there is nothing about v cant be fraction

Answer (score 2):

Min Distance between truck d = $\frac{v^2}{100}+\frac v 4$

Min Time between two trucks t = $\frac{v}{100}+\frac 1 4$

Then min time will achieve with v=0 and every $\frac 1 4$h (reaction distance $\frac v 4$ km? The coefficient may need to be adjusted).

This solution v=0 is stupid. That means infinity trucks are packed together in unit distance, which is impossible. Why?

So we need a truck length term.
Min Distance between truck = $\frac{v^2}{100}+\frac v 4+a$

Min Time between two trucks t = $\frac{v}{100}+\frac 1 4+ \frac a v$

Then find $\frac{dt}{dv}=0$, we have $v=10\sqrt a$ and Min Time = $\frac{\sqrt a}{5}+\frac1 4$